# Whitespace in wrapped form element

Tags: css

I'm creating a form with gradient borders. To protect against the borders being removed by the browser on autocomplete I've had to wrap all of the elements in a DIV containing their border. `box-sizing` is used to include the padding in the element size because there's a textarea too. My issue is now with the submit button.

```css
.input-container {
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
    border: solid 5px transparent;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #006699, #9900CC);
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" required>
</div>
```

When a user hovers over the button there's an issue where there's a slight edge. For ease having the border there all of the time makes more sense. Having the border there always means the button only needs to fill rather than having no border and being entirely fill (it causes size to momentarily change)

Any ideas for how to get rid of this small outline on the edges would be appreciated so that the button looks truly filled.

[image: Example of outline]

You can see the outline appear occasionally below.

[image: Outline appearing when hovering]

And static here

[image: Static example]

Comment: And also you can use tag a instead of input cause this problem is because you are using input tag, if i was you i would use <a type="submit">.
i guess its much better.

Answer (score 3):

Is it ok?

```css
.input-container:hover {
border: none;

}

.input-container {
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: solid 5px transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.input-container:hover input[type=submit] {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #006699, #9900CC);
    color: #FFFFFF;
padding:30px 15px;
    padding: 20px 15px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" required>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is also one of approach to fix without removing outer div. Upvoting this.

Comment: It seems to work but your answer could use a little more explanation as to why for anyone coming across this in the future. I'm yet to try an implementation.

Comment: Well i can't understand why you don't check me as an answer but i tell what i've did:
look i change the div hover to input container class then when you hover on the container border gets invisible and the input increases padding while you hover it thats all :)

Comment: but as i told you in a comment.
its better to not to use input use <a> and your styles get much better and short.

Answer (score 2):

As we can see. the border causes this part `background-image: linear-gradient(white, white)` in `.input-container`. So lets manipulate it. Added an additional class to parent container `.submit-container`.

```css
.input-container {
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
  border: solid 5px transparent;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.submit-container:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
}

input[type=submit] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: none;
}

.submit-container:hover input[type=submit] {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container submit-container">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" required>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This white border comes because of padding of outer div. You can do different way like removing div.

```css
input[type=submit] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
  border: solid 5px transparent;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #006699, #9900CC);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 18px;
  border: solid 5px transparent;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" required>
```

Comment: This approach could work but I mentioned in my question why it doesn't. Doing this repositions the whole button and its inner content meaning the text moves.

Answer (score 0):

it's because the white linear-gradient on the wrapper background.

below I gave to the gradient the colors of the button and it's look fine now

```css
.input-container {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #006699, #9900CC), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
    border: solid 5px transparent;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #006699, #9900CC);
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" required>
</div>
```

Comment: I can still see borders.