# A more suitable way to change submit button behaviour

Tags: html, css

Yes, I have asked this before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62268305/whitespace-in-wrapped-form-element) but none of the answers were suitable or they broke other things within the site so I've opted to post it again in the hopes that there's a more simple approach possible and that this question becomes easier to understand.

I have this form:

```css
::placeholder {
    color: #000000;
}

input[type=name],
input[type=textarea],
input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.site-input-container {
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
    border: solid 5px transparent;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.site-message-container {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
    border: solid 5px transparent;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.site-form-holder {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 190px;
    max-height: 190px;
    padding: 15px;
    resize: none;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #006699, #9900CC);
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-form-holder">
  <form method="post" name="process" action="process" autocomplete="off">

    <div class="site-input-container">
      <input type="name" id="forename" name="forename" placeholder="Forename" required=""> <br>
    </div>

    <div class="site-message-container">
      <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your message." maxlength="1000" required=""></textarea>
    </div>


    <div class="site-input-container site-submit-container">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Contact Us" required="">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Things to note are that yes I know name isn't an input type but I've defined it so that the html is easier for others to understand. I've also had to contain all of the inputs so that autocomplete within browsers doesn't remove the background image border.

My issue lies with the submit button because there's an outline. I've included more complete code this time in the hopes that it can stick with HEX for colours and make the issue easier to solve.

The problem is that when the button is hovered over there's white space like this:

[image: Example Static]

And this:

[image: Example GIF]

I've posted this question here with a more complete view of the form as well as more code in the hopes that a better approach can be reached than the original as none of them managed to fit together.

Any approaches would be useful to make the button fill completely without any white outlines. I can't remove borders as the button can temporarily change size looking like a glitch.

`EDIT`
The approach in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62354280/12007347) from [Bryce Howitson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6268914/bryce-howitson) is close but the when you look closely (it'll be more prevalent on mobile) you can see that the gradients don't perfectly match. It's a momentary hover on a desktop but would last longer on mobile.

[image: Not seamless]

If there's a way to make this look seamless that would be great.

## EDIT

Not a duplicate and it was clearly explained why.

Comment: Why were the previous answers not acceptable? Multiple responses seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: It didn't work with other elements of my site because of the :hover functionality. I've now added all of the CSS for each element in the hopes that something can be done that wouldn't affect all.

Comment: Just a reminder, hovers don't work on touch devices so mobile isn't a great use case. Yes, you can replicate a hover but that often breaks usability expectations.

Comment: you got multiple answers to your old question  and you didn't even reply to them to say why they aren't suitable. You are not allowe to repeat the same question because the answer aren't suitable

Comment: This is the same question as the one you already asked. If you are dissatisfied with existing answers to a question, add a bounty or edit the question to add more clarity to your desired outcome. [tag:css] is a popular tag; if you post an adequate bounty you are sure to get tons of responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you can just move the hover to the `.site-submit-container` which according to your code is unused... Then on hover, you remove the white linear gradient and replace it with the colored gradient.

```css
::placeholder {
    color: #000000;
}

input[type=name],
input[type=company],
input[type=email],
input[type=textarea],
input[type=submit],
input[type=tel] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.site-input-container {
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
    border: solid 5px transparent;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.site-message-container {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
    border: solid 5px transparent;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.site-form-holder {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 190px;
    max-height: 190px;
    padding: 15px;
    resize: none;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.site-submit-container:hover {
background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #006699, #9900CC), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC); 
}
.site-submit-container:hover input {
   background: transparent;
   color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-form-holder">
  <form method="post" name="process" action="process" autocomplete="off">

    <div class="site-input-container">
      <input type="name" id="forename" name="forename" placeholder="Forename" required=""> <br>
    </div>

    <div class="site-message-container">
      <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your message." maxlength="1000" required=""></textarea>
    </div>


    <div class="site-input-container site-submit-container">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Contact Us" required="">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Edit: It seems like a less complex solution to simply stack two elements and then turn one background transparent. And use `padding` on the wrapper to replicate the border. This way you don't need to have gradient borders.

```css
::placeholder {
    color: #000000;
}

input[type=name],
input[type=company],
input[type=email],
input[type=textarea],
input[type=submit],
input[type=tel] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.site-input-container {
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
    border: solid 5px transparent;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.site-message-container {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
    border: solid 5px transparent;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.site-form-holder {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 190px;
    max-height: 190px;
    padding: 15px;
    resize: none;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
/* part I added overrides a few styles above */
.site-submit-container {
 background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #006699, #9900CC);
 border: none;
 padding: 5px;
}
.site-submit-container:hover input {
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-form-holder">
 <form method="post" name="process" action="process" autocomplete="off">

  <div class="site-input-container">
   <input type="name" id="forename" name="forename" placeholder="Forename" required=""> <br>
  </div>

  <div class="site-message-container">
   <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your message." maxlength="1000" required=""></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="site-input-container site-submit-container">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Contact Us" required="">
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: That was in my code from another attempt and I forgot to remove it. This is a close approach and I'll try it now, the gradient just doesn't completely match up with its border.

Comment: It's certainly closer than I was but it isn't seamless so it's evident that the gradient isn't exactly right.

Comment: I think the multiple gradient approach is actually the problem. because you're hoping that the sub-pixels on a screen will match up between elements. I'll update my answer with a better solution.

Comment: I've just fixed it, don't worry. (fix was to just use linear gradient fill on hover)

Comment: Still seems like an overly complex solution when you could just stack two elements...

Comment: That's true but it's working and I don't care for redoing it now. It also has to be this way so that chrome autocomplete doesn't strip the background image given gradient borders aren't naively supported.

Comment: Well trying to get gradient borders doesn't help you. Just remove the border and give the wrapper 5px of padding. The input element's white background will make it look like a border.

Comment: Gradient borders are needed for the design though, using linear gradient for all fixes the issue. I've tried multiple approaches but this works best across the form with minimal styles because of autocomplete and hover.

Comment: My point is they don't have to be gradient borders. They just have to *look* like gradient borders. Padding does that effectively at least on the submit button but I would guess it works on all the other elements too.