# Seamless gradient fill on DIV with outline

Tags: html, css

I asked a question here for [a more suitable way to change submit button behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354061/a-more-suitable-way-to-change-submit-button-behaviour) and while the answer has been accepted because it's suitable it isn't the desired effect.

Yes it gets rid of the white border between the border and the inner of the submit button but this button will be used in other places too so the gradient needs to be smooth.

At the moment if you look closely you'll notice that the border isn't seamless. I need a way to make the gradient appear as though it's the entire button and it not be clear that there's a border.

[image: Image showing]

In the image above you can see that the gradient isn't seamless with the border too, is there a way to achieve this? For the entire form you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354061/a-more-suitable-way-to-change-submit-button-behaviour).

```css
.size {
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.site-input-container {
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
  border: solid 5px transparent;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.site-submit-container:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #006699, #9900CC), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
}

.site-submit-container:hover input {
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
}

input[type=submit] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="size">
  <form>
    <div class="site-input-container site-submit-container">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Contact Us" required="">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

It isn't the most noticeable thing ever but it isn't ideal. Because I've had to use DIVs to contain it there needs to be a way to make it look seamless as a normal button would be done differently. I have to keep this as it's how the page is set up and it's easier to match the rest of the form.

It's even clearer why it needs to be seamless when the button is smaller
[image: Smaller button]

Comment: Are you sure that you need a border at all? Why not just use padding?

Comment: I already gave a similar answer to your old quesiton, it's not suitable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62270135/8620333 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two linear gradients fixes this.

```
.site-submit-container:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #006699, #9900CC), linear-gradient(-45deg, #006699, #9900CC);
}
```